# Using Retrieve message to get an Entity

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am creating a plugin for Dynamics CRM 2011 to be executed when a user opening a lead. So i'm using a Retrieve message to execute plug-in.

```
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)

serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

Entity entity;

if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&

context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
{
    entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

But i'm always ending up with return. When i'm using it whith Update message it works perfectly fine. How can i get the lead Entity when executing plug-in on Retrive message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `Retrieve` message the right parameter to check is `BusinessEntity` inside `OutputParameters`

try with

```cs
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

Entity entity;

if (context.OutputParameters.Contains("BusinessEntity") &&

context.OutputParameters["BusinessEntity"] is Entity)
{
    entity = (Entity)context.OutputParameters["BusinessEntity"];
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Still the same. Maybe i shuould use a particular pipeline? Like sync pre or post?

Comment: which steps you are using now?

Comment: Thanks everything is working now. Changed step from Synchronous Pre-operation to Synchronous Post-operation